# Do I need to install all these 3 libs or just one? OpenCV

Tags: anaconda, opencv, python

Have read many SOF questions about OPENCV, they all tell me what each of them is.

When I see so many different but similar names, I feel great confusion.
I thought I need to just install opencv-python, but then out of sudden, I found there is another one which looks correct to me as well, py-opencv.... Gosh which one is the correct?!!!

So my question is:
In a newly created conda environment, I'd like to add open-cv to use in my Python Jupyter Notebook. Do I need to install all of them or just one?

**Them**: opencv, [Python-OpenCV(opencv-python)](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), py-opencv, libopencv

**One**: py-opencv or opencv-python

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to go with ``opencv-contrib-python``. It has the whole functionality. Here the link https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/.

Comment: thanks @programandoconro It seems the open-cv-contrib-python is a good option for new starter. Good suggestion. Do you know what's the differences between py-opencv and opencv-python?

Comment: I have the exact same question. I chose opencv and installed it. Other packages libopencv and py-opencv is installed along with opencv.
Choose opencv others will be installed in anaconda as a dependency.